# Existence of Hamiltonian for Planar Ordinary Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Consider the following planar ODE $$ \begin{cases} \dot x = f(x,y) \\ \dot y = g(x,y) \end{cases} $$ and suppose $ \frac{\partial f }{\partial x} +  \frac{\partial g }{\partial y} = 0$. Is this a sufficient and necessary condition for the existence of a Hamiltonian (or any first integral) for the system?

Comment: Up to some domain and regularity assumptions, the answer is yes: do it yourself by trying to solve $f=\partial H/\partial y$ and $g=-\partial H/\partial x$.

Comment: @JohnB I wasn't successful with the method that you've suggested. However, zero divergence condition coincides with condition for exactness of some auxiliary equation, and the potential function for this equation is exactly a Hamiltonian of original system.

Comment: @Evgeny Exactly. My suggestion corresponds to the proof of what you describe (see my answer to the question clarifying this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say that we are on a rectangle (for simplicity) and that $f$ and $g$ are $C^1$.

Integrating $f=\partial H/\partial y$ with respect to $y$ gives
$$
\int_{y_0}^y f(x,s) \, d s =H(x,y)-H(x,y_0).
$$
Similarly, integrating $g=-\partial H/\partial x$ with respect to $x$ for $y=y_0$ gives
$$
\int_{x_0}^x g(s,y_0) \, d s =-H(x,y_0)+H(x_0,y_0).
$$
Subtracting the two yields the identity
$$
H(x,y)=H(x_0,y_0)+\int_{y_0}^y f(x,s) \, d s-\int_{x_0}^x g(s,y_0) \, d s.
$$

> So we are led to consider
>   $$
> H(x,y)=\int_{y_0}^y f(x,s) \, d s-\int_{x_0}^x g(s,y_0) \, d s
> $$
>   (the constant doesn't matter).

Note that indeed $\partial H/\partial y=f$ and
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}(x,y)
&=\int_{y_0}^y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,s) \, d s-g(x,y_0)\\
&=-\int_{y_0}^y \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,s) \, d s-g(x,y_0)\\
&=-g(x,y).
\end{split}
$$

The other direction is simpler (since $f$ and $g$ are $C^1$, the Hamiltonian $H$ is $C^2$).